# Creating an object in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to save the `noteText` inside a text, but it's becoming a problem. I would like to make an object with the same attributes: name, date, note and to display only the name and date. Also, I would like, when I create a `Note`to map it in an array. Like so

```
let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key)=>{
        return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
                deleteMethod={()=>this.deleteNote(key)} openNote={()=>this.openNote(key)}/>
    });
```

And here is how I add an item:

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.noteArray.push({
                'noteNumber':'Note '+ this.props.navigation.state.params.noteArray[key],
                'date':d.getFullYear()+
                "/"+(d.getMonth()+1) +
                "/"+ d.getDate(),
                'note': this.state.noteText
            });
```

Here is the class note:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
View,
Text,
StyleSheet,
TouchableOpacity,
TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';


export default class Note extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={this.props.keyval}  onPress={this.props.openNote}>
            <View style={styles.note}>
                <Text style={styles.noteDate}>{this.props.val.noteNumber}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.noteDate}>{this.props.val.date}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.val.note}</Text>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.deleteMethod} style={styles.noteDelete}>
                    <Text style={styles.noteDeleteText}>Del</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
}
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
note: {
    position: 'relative',
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    paddingRight: 100,
    borderLeftWidth:1,
    borderLeftColor: '#000',
    borderRightWidth:1,
    borderRightColor: '#000',
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderBottomColor: '#000'
},
noteDate:{
    paddingLeft: 20,
    borderLeftWidth: 10,
    borderLeftColor: '#0000FF'
},
noteText: {
    paddingLeft: 20,
    borderLeftWidth: 10,
    borderLeftColor: '#0000FF',
    opacity: 0,
},
noteDelete: {
    position: 'absolute',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
    padding: 10,
    top: 10,
    bottom: 10,
    right: 10
},
noteDeleteText: {
    color: 'white'
},
});
```

Comment: what navigation library are you using?

Comment: Would you like to post all the classes to get a general idea? It's kind of hard to explain.

Comment: If you think it'll help, go ahead

Comment: I actually solved the problem! :))

Sorry for wasting your time! :/

Comment: post your solution here, so other people can consult later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example I worked on:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
 state = { counter: this.props.startsWith };

 ...
}
```

In stead of `Counter`, I used `Note` itself.